# Is there any way to prevent the Dock from jumping to another display when I reach the bottom of the screen?

Tags: dock, gesture

When your mouse reaches the bottom of the screen then try to drag it a little bit lower, macOS automatically moves the Dock to that display. I trigger this unintentionally a few times a day, so I want to turn it off to keep the Dock on my main display. Is there a way for that?

I am not open for attaching the Dock to the side of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices.

1. Attach it to the side of the screen - which you already said you don't want to do.
2. Disable "Displays have separate Spaces" In Mission Control.
   This will have the side effect of making all your Spaces move in 'pairs', both screens are now one larger Space, rather than two independent, smaller Spaces.
   The dock, however, will then always remain on your primary display.

Personally, I've always used 2. I just prefer my screen layout that way.

Comment: You are right, those two solves it, but I like to have attached screens in Spaces, so this will not solve my issue. :(